# Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?). OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that accepts an int n and returns a list that runs down from n to 0.

This is what I have

```
let rec downFrom n =
let m = n+1 in
if m = 0 then                                                                                  
  []                                                                                           
else                                                                                            
  (m-1) :: downFrom (m - 1);;
```

The function compiles ok but when I test it with any int it gives me the error
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).

I know it's the local varible that gets in the way but I don't know another way to declare it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the *real* thing wrong with your program is that you have an infinite loop.  Why, because your inductive base case is 0, but you always stay at `n`!  This is because you recurse on `m - 1` which is really `n + 1 - 1`

I'm surprised as to why this compiles, because it doesn't include the `rec` keyword, which is necessary on recursive functions.  To avoid stack overflows in OCaml, you generally switch to a [tail recursive](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion) style, such as follows:

```
let downFrom n =
  let rec h n acc = 
    if n = 0 then List.rev acc else h (n-1) (n::acc)
  in
  h n []
```

---

Someone suggested the following edit:

```
let downFrom n =
    let rec h m acc =
        if m > n then acc else h (m + 1) (m::acc)
    in
    h 0 [];
```

This saves a call to List.rev, I agree.

Comment: thank you! although i havent learn tail recursion, i changed the last statement to (m-1) :: downFrom (m - 2) and it worked

Comment: as a hint, I would (for better style) simply eliminate the definition of m, and instead replace it by n+1 everywhere, otherwise it looks awkward.

Comment: I have corrected a few typos to have your version of `downFrom` compile. But still, it returns an increasing list, while the OP asks for a decreasing list.

Answer (score 1):

The key with recursion is that the recursive call has to be a smaller version of the problem.  Your recursive call doesn't create a smaller version of the problem.  It just repeats the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a filtering parameter
syntax:

```
let f = function
   p1 -> expr1
 | p2 -> expr2
 | p3 -> ...;;
```

---

```
let rec n_to_one =function
  0->[]
  |n->n::n_to_one (n-1);;

# n_to_one 3;;
- : int list = [3; 2; 1]
```